# How to filter tags by category in woocommerce?

Tags: tags, woocommerce, categories

In `Woocommerce 2.4.7`, **for example**, If I click on `Starwars` tag, I would see the store page with all the Star Wars items and I will see in the sidebar that I have `14 Star Wars items in DVD, 50 Star Wars items in Toys, 14 Star Wars items in T-shirts`.

But if I click in any of these categories, **for example** `DVD`, Woocommerce takes me to the category page where I will see all the DVDs from my store and not only the Star Wars DVDs...

**In the tag page does anyone know a way to filter by category the results of that tag?**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I found how to do it using this plugin.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-products-filter/

Comment: I was also going to suggest some special [rewrite rules](http://thereforei.am/2011/10/28/advanced-taxonomy-queries-with-pretty-urls/)